# Can I check the security policies hit-count in juniper routers via SNMP?

Tags: snmp, juniper-srx

Am trying to see if there is a way to get the output of "show security policies hit-count descending" via SNMP,

it has the following o/p like so,

```
show security policies hit-count descending 
node0:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------

Logical system: root-logical-system
 Index   From zone        To zone           Name           Policy count
 1       WIFI-DEVICETEST  UNTRUST           allow-internet-traffic-only 284046       
 2       USERS            UNTRUST           allow-all      273438       
 3       AV               UNTRUST           allow-media-to-internet 187757
```

The closest MIB i came to where info related to security policies were is "jnxJsSecPolicyMIB" but Iam unable to figure out how to get the hit count using the MIB.
Any help much appreciated.